# Spring forward, fall back

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Aujourd'hui au Canada on a mis à jour les horloges. Afin de se rappeler lequel est le bon sens, on a recours à une expression fréquente : « Spring forward, fall back. » En printemps on va en avant alors qu'en automne en va en arrière.

Bien entendu, cela marche seulement parce que le mot « spring » est un homonyme qui veut dire et « printemps » et « bondir », tandis que le mot « fall » est un homonyme qui veut dire et « automne » et « tomber ». Comme cette coïncidence n'existe pas en français, je suppose que ce moyen mnémotechnique ne fonctionne pas.

Est-ce qu'il y a une autre manière universellement répandue de se rappeler comment il faut ajuster l'horloge ?

Comment: À ma connaissance, on n'a pas de moyen mnémotechnique. C'est peut-être pour ça qu'on a voté massivement pour l'abandon des changements d'heure... ;-)

Comment: Comme il s'agit d'un [marronnier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marronnier_(journalisme)) on a aussi rarement besoin de s'en rappeler, les journalistes s'en chargent pour nous :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. Tout à fait... Néanmoins, pour une raison ou une autre on insiste sur l'invention de telles choses :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je viens d'entendre d'une francophone qui habite au Canada qu'on emploie une replique phonétique plutôt que sémantique :

> *En **av**ril on **av**ance : en octob**re** on **re**cule.*

Je propose ceci comme réponse pour voir si les autres s'y accorderont ou diront par contre que ce soit l'invention astucieuse mais inconnue de quelqu'un et qu'on ne le dit pas. :)

---

Grâce à Greg dans les commentaires, voici ce dessin de Philippe Geluck qui affirme la chose, au moins pour ce qui est du Canada et de la Belgique :

[image: Changement d'heure par Philippe Geluck]

Comment: J'ai découvert  ce fabuleux moyen mnémotechnique il y a queqlues années en Belgique également (si mes souvenirs sont bons, tout bêtement via un post Facebook). La formule exacte que j'ai en tête est "en AVril on AVance. En octobRE on REcule".

Comment: @Greg Ah, Facebook, qui réunit toutes les cultures ... Merci ! Faute d'une meilleure réponse je modifierai et accepterai celle-ci un peu plus tard.

Comment: J'ai appris ce même moyen mnémotechnique grâce à mon grand-père (belge).

Comment: @Greg En Belgique on n'avance pas en avril, mais le dernier weekend de mars...

Comment: Bien sûr: le dernier dimanche de mars, soit quelques jours avant avril. C'est un simple moyen mnémotechnique facile à appliquer quand on est confronté au changement d'heure,  pas une règle précise pour savoir quand il faut faire le changement. Quand on arrive fin mars, on est presque en avril, et c'est là que ce "truc" est facile à appliquer.

Comment: À y réfléchir,  je pense que j'ai découvert ce truc par ce dessin, signé d'un dessinateur belge (Philippe Geluck). Encore un Belge, décidément...https://images.app.goo.gl/rZi1oqqRMLgMBxym6

Comment: @Greg Le chat de Geluck a toujours raison. Je retire ma remarque.

Answer (score 0):

La possibilité suivante demande un peu de réflexion mais elle comporte un repère bien connu, l'heure du  crépuscule.

- L'heure du crépuscule avance/recule dans la saison avancez/reculez l'heure.

*ou, plus concis*

- L'heure du crépuscule avance, avancez l'heure et inversement.

En utilisant l'aube il faut inverser les verbes et ce n'est pas aussi pratique, apparemment.